# Check if string contains a substring from a list Excel VBA

Tags: vba, list, excel, substring

I have cells that contain account numbers in column A and strings that contain text and account numbers in column B.

[Data example]

[image]

I would like to create a list of accounts and then check if any of those accounts is contained in column B. If it is I want to extract this account number to column C (in the same row it was found). I am a VBA noob so I'm not sure how this could be done.

I asked a similar but much more complex question earlier this week, but this should be easier to "solve".

[This is how I would like it to look like after processing]

[image]

There might be other numbers with the same length as the account numbers in column B that are NOT account numbers, so this excludes some solutions.

Comment: Please update this question with a small sample of the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

In cell C1, use this formula and copy down:

```
=IF(A1="",INDEX($A$1:$A$16,MATCH(1,INDEX(COUNTIF(B1,"*"&$A$1:$A$16&"*")*($A$1:$A$16<>""),),0)),A1)
```

Comment: This unfortunately works only with accounts starting with "1". Is it possible to modify it to work with accounts starting with "2" as well?

Comment: @xLokos ??? There's nothing in the formula to only work with accounts starting with 1. If it's not providing correct results, you'll need to provide additional sample data so that I can see what's going on.